# Select tag status check with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have two select tags now what i want is that only one should be selected at a time that is from two select tags user should only select one and if the user select from both the tags then it should display error that only one should be selected

What i am using

```
var $institution=document.getElementById('institutionselect').value;
var $section=document.getElementById('sectionselect').value;

if($institution.selectedIndex = 0 && $section.selectedIndex = 0){ 
    alert('please select one amongst two');
    return false;

}else if($institution.selectedIndex = null && $section.selectedIndex = null){ 
    alert('please select one amongst two');
    return false;
}
```

Please help in correcting the code Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are assigning instead of comparing. Use `==` instead of `=`.

```
if($institution.selectedIndex = 0 && $section.selectedIndex = 0)
```

Also update this line removing `.value` in order to use `.selectedIndex`:

```
var $institution=document.getElementById('institutionselect');
var $section=document.getElementById('sectionselect');
```

An example:

```js
var check = function() {
  var $institution = document.getElementById('institutionselect');
  var $section = document.getElementById('sectionselect');
  if ($institution.selectedIndex == 0 && $section.selectedIndex == 0) {
    alert('please select one amongst two');
    return false;
  }
};
```

```html
<select id='institutionselect'>
  <option>Select</option>
  <option>Item 1</option>
  <option>Item 2</option>
</select>
<select id='sectionselect'>
  <option>Select</option>
  <option>Item 1</option>
  <option>Item 2</option>
</select>
<button onclick="check();">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is checking for both value in one condition like so :

```
 var $institution = document.getElementById('institutionselect').value;
 var $section     = document.getElementById('sectionselect').value;

 // if both variable have values
 if ( $institution && $section ){
   alert('please select one amongst two');
   return;  
 }

 // do something here
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/rw0rapvb/)